# How to interpolate between multiple biome height-maps?

Tags: c#, procedural-generation, heightmap

For biome area distribution I combine perlin noise representing temperature, and moisture levels using voronoi cell distribution. The world is divided by some modulo and another perlin noise function to return a voronoi control point. The seams between biomes show. I thought a simple weight function will do:

[image: An example of weight calculation for adjacent points]

Orange point = the sample point which the weights will be calculated according to.

Using cellular noise (some kind of voronoi distribution similar to what I'm looking for, but doesn't blend different biomes):

[image: An example of Cellular noise heightmap]

To clarify vertex height:

```
float HeightAtPosition(float x, float z)
{
    //Returns an array containing information of all the adjacent biome 
    //control points(mainly their position and their biome type)
    BiomeControlPoint[] adjacentControlPoints = GetAdjacentBiomePoints(x, z);
    //Returns an array containing values between 0 and 1
    //Iputs: An array of all the adjacent biome points, a sample coordinate
    //Output: A float array containing the weight of each biome on the 
    //        coordinate(between 0 and 1)
    float[] weights = CalcWeights(adjacentControlPoints, new Vector2(x, z));
    float finalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < adjacentControlPoints.Length; i++)
    {
        finalHeight += adjacentControlPoints[i] * weights[i];
    }
    return finalHeight;
}
```

A good solution if `GetAdjacentBiomePoints(x, z)` and `CalcWeights(adjacentControlPoints, new Vector2(x, z))` were more performance efficient. [Bilinear interpolation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujGW5y1x7Jg) I don't understand.

Comment: Is there a question in there, or are you just asking for opinions on something?

Comment: I would use the perlin noise function you already have to calculate biome properties, and then find the specific biome based on its properties.  For example, you could use your noise function to calculate rainfall and temperature, and high rainfall/high temperature would be jungle, and low rainfall high temperature would be desert, etc.

Comment: Leo Bartkus: I'm familiar with this method and I'm using this method combined with a voronoi diagram for the biome distribution.
Ron Beyer: Yes... there is a question if anyone can think of a better way to interpolate between biomes noise functions rather than the way I specified, That way is alittle to performance costing in the future event of chunks generating fluently as the player moves around in the world, Maybe a bilinear interpulation but I'm not quite sure how to implement or rather how would it contribute for this cause at all so I'm hoping for some more experienced opinion.
Thanks

Comment: Also I'm having some difficulties implementing the GetAdjacentBiomePoints() method, I want to only get the relevant points in an efficient way

Answer (score 0):

You could try a weighted voronoi diagram. My php implementation:https://tetramatrix.github.io/awvd/.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the other way:

- generate temperature and moisture levels for each pixel
- generate how much each biome matches those values

  - precalculate strength of each biome as a 2d lookup table?
- take the X best matches
- normalize the strengths (sum is 1)
- your a unique noise function combination is weighted sum of the X best biomes

Personally I work with gridmaps and interpolate the biome's valus from a small map with large cells to a large map with small cells. Interpolation is much easier there:

- [MapInterpolator.java](https://github.com/Orchaldir/FantasyWorldSimulation/blob/master/FantasyWorldSimulation/src/jfws/util/map/MapInterpolator.java)
- [interpolation classes](https://github.com/Orchaldir/FantasyWorldSimulation/tree/master/FantasyWorldSimulation/src/jfws/util/math/interpolation)

Sorry that it is java.